# Underscore / Coffeescript generates some weird code, how to refactor for code coverage?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js, code-coverage

Within my Mocha tests, I have the following coffeescript:

```
_u = require "underscore"

...

player._id.toString() in _u.map team._players, (player) ->
  player._id.toString()
```

And this compiles to:

```
var _u,
  __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

...

return _ref = player._id.toString(), __indexOf.call(_u.map(team._players, function(player) {
  return player._id.toString();
}), _ref) >= 0;
```

Firstly, I don't really understand the compiled code at all, is it an artifact of coffeescript + underscore, is there a way to rewrite my code to avoid it?

The problem however is that `[].indexOf` appears to always be true, and so the `|| ...` never fires and I get a blip on my Istanbul code coverage report. I'd also happily exclude it with istanbul's `ignore` statements however because it's generated, I can't target it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `underscore` isn't significant.

```
a in b
```

is compiled as:

```
__indexOf.call(b, a) >= 0;
```

(try this in the Coffeescript.org `Try` screen.)

Coffeescript defines (this is standard boilerplate):

```
var __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) ...
```

Normally this gives `[].indexOf`, the normal `in` function for arrays.  But some older browsers don't have this array method (`[].indexOf` is `undefined`).  The `function ...` part of that expression accomplishes the same thing with a loop over the array.

If you don't want this piece of Coffeescript boilerplate, don't use 'in'.   For example use:

```
b.indexOf(a)>=0
```

There is probably a way of doing this purely with `underscore`.

Comment: This.  It *does* run the code after `||` in browsers that don't implement `Array.indexOf`.  If you're running tests in one that does, then it won't hit that code.  "100% code coverage" is a useless metric to strive for.  Your tests do not need to hit 100% of the code, as long as they test 100% of the functionality.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll hunt an underscore or lodash method for this. @nzifnab, while I agree that striving for 100% is not a great metric, I find that having 100% on my coverage report across the many modules I'm testing makes it very simple to quickly see where I'm missing things. If I was satisfied with 98.5% or something, then the number would constantly bounce around and I'd have to individually check each file for untested code. Not the worst problem in the world, but it's one of the reasons istanbul provides ignore statements.

Comment: `_u.find` should return the matching `player` or `undefined`.